# Type inference success depends on naming a value

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I'm still new to TypeScript and frequently find things I find really odd.

Take this code:

```
interface MyInterface<T> {
    [i: string]: T;
}

function myFunc<T>(arg: MyInterface<T>) { }

var o = { 'val1': 42, 'val2': 43 };

myFunc(o);
```

The call fails with the complaint that the "Index signature is missing".

Interestingly, it's not missing when I write

```
myFunc({ 'val1': 42, 'val2': 43 });
```

That would mean that the expression `{ 'val1': 42, 'val2': 43 }`'s type is inferred backwards from the call (which is somewhat expected), but not so when bound to a name (which is weird and not how I know backward inference to work from F#, for example).

But it gets even stranger.

If I change the interface to

```
interface MyInterface<T> {
    [i: number]: T;
}
```

then the corresponding

```
var o = [42, 43];

myFunc(o);
```

also works (in addition to passing the array directly).

Is that by design? What are the rules that explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this inconsistency is because you're using TypeScript 1.8. If you try either out in the TypeScript playground, [you'll see either one works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MyInterface%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bi%3A%20string%5D%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20myFunc%3CT%3E(arg%3A%20MyInterface%3CT%3E)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20o%20%3D%20%7B%20'val1'%3A%2042%2C%20'val2'%3A%2043%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AmyFunc(o)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AmyFunc(%7B%20'val1'%3A%2042%2C%20'val2'%3A%2043%20%7D)%3B).

The reason for this behavior in TS 1.8 is because when you placed the object literal directly in the call to `myFunc`, it was *contextually typed* by `arg`, whose type has an index signature. As a result, the inferred type gained an index signature.

Contextual typing doesn't modify a variable's prior inferred type (the *declared type*), so when you tried to pass `o` to `myFunc`, you got an error that `o` was missing an index signature.

In TypeScript 2.0 (and above), these scenarios were painful enough that we brought in the concept of *implicit index signatures*. Check out the pull request here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7029.

To quote:

> With this PR an object literal type is assignable to a type with an index signature if all known properties in the object literal are assignable to that index signature. This makes it possible to pass a variable that was initialized with an object literal as parameter to a function that expects a map or dictionary:

```
function httpService(path: string, headers: { [x: string]: string }) { }

const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
};

httpService("", { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });  // Ok
httpService("", headers);  // Now ok, previously wasn't
```

Comment: But to be clear, the improvement is only regarding index signatures specifically and there still is the difference between the declared type and the contextual type, correct? I think in F# there's not such distinction.

Comment: Correct - the way that types are inferred does not use unification systems that you'll find in languages like F#. There's an advantage to this locality in that it's easier to reason about how the language infers a type - inference is limited to the statement level (though recall that each statement can contain multiple statements through function expressions and the like).